# How to get Instance of a Class using reflection in java having generics parameter and return type method?

Tags: java, class, methods, reflection

```
public enum E{
E1,E2,E3
}

public class Service{
...
}

public interface A<RET>{
  RET get();
}

public interface AI<RET,CONF> extends A<RET>{
   void conf(CONF ...args);
}

public class AC implements AI<Service,E>{
  public void conf(E ...args){
   ....
 }
public Service get(){
  return new Service();
}
}
```

Now when I am trying with reflection to create Instance of Class "AC" I am getting error:

```
public Class MyReflectionAPI{
  public Object getInstance(){
       Class <? extends AI> aClass = (Class <? extends AI>) Class.forName("AC");
       Constructor<? extends AI> aCon = aClass.getConstructor(null);
       AI ai = aCon.newInstance((Object[]) null);

        Class<?> typeArg = Class.forName("[L"+"E"+";");
        Method valueOfTypeArg = typeArg.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
        Object obj[] = new Object[]{valueOfTypeArg.invoke(typeArg,"E1")};
        ai.conf(obj);
    }

}
```

giving me the error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [E;

Is there any way of getting an object of Instance of AC class with generic objects passed to it?

Comment: Hey! Not sure what class `"[L"+"E"+";"` is supposed to be. Could you explain that please?

Comment: here "[L" and ";" added to read array type class of Type "E", here E is Enum, As you can see in the question having values enum E {E1,E2,E3}

Comment: Your code does not even compile; you are notoriously writing `Class` instead of `class`. Then, your attempt to invoke a `valueOf` method on an array will already fail, so you never get to the point where the code would produce a `ClassCastException`. You should provide a [mcve] instead of pseudo code that has never seen a compiler.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for correcting me, I have updated. Actually I can't post the actual code so need to create the demo version of it. I am apologies for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java arrays know their component type. So you would need to create array reflectively. Try the following.

```
Class<?> typeE = Class.forName("E");
Object obj = Array.newInstance(typeE,1);
Array.set(obj,0,valueOfTypeArg.invoke(typeE,"E1"));
ai.conf((Object[])obj);    // good reason to hate varargs
```

Comment: No reason to hate varargs. Just simplify your code: `Class<? extends Enum> typeE = Class.forName( "E").asSubclass(Enum.class); Object[] arr = (Object[])Array.newInstance(typeE, 1); arr[0] = Enum.valueOf(typeE, "E1"); ai.conf(arr);`